# How can I make vim's mark feature noisy?

Tags: vim

I would like to use marks more.  I'm not terribly confident with them because they don't give me any feedback when I set them.  I'd like to see the output of `marks <key>` whenever I mark .  I'm hoping this is some setting I haven't found yet, but I'm open to config shenanigans as well.

Comment: Something like [vim-signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature) ?

Comment: Have you looked at showmarks.vim?

Comment: showmarks: yes. vim-signature: no.  I think showmarks clashed with gitgutter.  vim-signature supports some amount of interaction with gitgutter, so I'll be giving that a try.

Comment: vim-signature does the job.  Thanks, @Marth

Answer (score 1):

Something like [vim-signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature) ?
                    – Marth

vim-signature does the job.  Thanks, @Marth
                    – valadil